# FreeDOS driver for Krypton V.92 56K PCI device

Tags: drivers, modem

I would like to know where I could get a FreeDOS driver for my [Krypton V.92 56K](http://www.priyagroup.com/ithome/products/communi_products/pm560msu.shtml) PCI device.
...Is anybody using this hardware with FreeDOS? Please help me out. Even MS-DOS drivers would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

PCI and DOS don't play well together.  Couple that with the fact that, just by looking at the simplicity of the card, it's likely a Winmodem that relies on a driver to do most of the work, and your chances are slim to nil.

You should go to a local computer shop and see if they have any external voice modems.  RS-232 external modems will work with just about any operating system on the planet.  They're dirt cheap now; I picked mine up for $20 and I was able to use caller ID, record incoming voice from it, and most of the stuff mentioned in the link you provided.